# Deep changes of objects cannot be observed in mobx

Tags: reactjs, observable, mobx

I am managing the state using mobx(6.3.12) in react.
But I can't observe deep changes of objects.

Here my sources.

1. store

```
    class ApiStore {
        values = {
            name: '',
            author: '',
        }
        constructor() {
            makeObservable(this, {
                values: observable,
                setValues: action
            })
        }
              
        setValues(key, value) {
            values[key] = value;
        }
    }
```

2. observe(not all work)

   ```
   store = new ApiStore();

   useEffect(() => {
     console.log(values);
   }, [store.values]);



   store = new ApiStore();
       useEffect(() => {
           autorun(() => console.log(store.values));
       }, [])
   ```
3. state change

   ```
    ...
    <NormalTextValue
       onChange={(e) => store.setValues(id, e.target.value)}
       value={store.values[id]}/>
   ```

I realized that not being able to read deep change was the cause.
Changes can be detected by accessing them via dereferencing.
(ex. [store.values.name])

So I changed it to the following to get the desired result.

```
   setValues(key, value) {
       this.values[key] = value;
       this.values = {...this.values};
    }
```

**Q**:
According to the docs, the default option of observable is known as **.deep**.
So I thought I could automatically detect deep change of
object (through this.values[key] = values).
But it seems that the reference value of the object has to be changed.
Could you please explain this or point out the error?

Answer (score 2):

`deep` means that the object will be deeply `observable`, so every inner property or inner object/array, basically everything will be made `observable` too.

To actually react to the change of some `observable` value you need to use it, or `dot into it` or `touch it`, whatever you call it. So if you want to react to the `name` changes then you need to somehow use `store.values.name` inside of your component. Same with other fields. MobX will subscribe your component for changes only if you are actually explicitly using those values. Otherwise why would you want to rerender component if it does not use anything? It will be just an extra rerender.

In your case you are only using `store.values`, basically only the object itself, not its fields. That's why everything rerenders when you reassign the whole object with destructuring. You are using the object -> object changes -> component rerenders.

If you are not using all the fields but still want to somehow react to them you can, for example, use `JSON.stringify` or MobX method `toJS`, like that:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        // return is important, read why below
        return autorun(() => console.log(JSON.stringify(store.values)));
    }, [])
```

And quote from docs about `autorun`:

> Note that we return the disposer created by autorun from our effect function. This is important, since it makes sure the autorun gets cleaned up once the component unmounts!

Comment: You should also remove the braces from that useEffect callback so that the return value from `autorun` (the disposer) is returned as the cleanup function for the effect.

Comment: @portalguy15837 nice catch, thanks! I just copied from OP's post, but yes, in reality a disposer should always be returned.